# Find the imaginary part of $\ln(1-re^{ix})$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

I'm trying to prove that imaginary part of $\ln(1-re^{ix})$ is
$$\Im \left(\ln(1-re^{ix})\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{r\sin(x)}{1-r\cos(x)}\right).$$

I saw this assertation in the book "Trigonometric Series"

Comment: Just a question: is it $\ln(1-re^{ix})$ or $\ln(1-r e^{i}x)$?

Comment: The first one, as it written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z = |z|e^{i\alpha} = 1 - re^{ix} = (1 - r\cos x) -ir\sin x$. Note that $$\log z = \log\left(|z|e^{i\alpha}\right) = \log |z| + i\alpha$$

whose imaginary part is $\alpha$. So we need only evaluate $\alpha$. But $\alpha = \arg(1-re^{ix})$ and we have $1-re^{ix}= (1-r\cos x) - ir\sin x$, from which we can conclude $\alpha = \arctan \frac{r\sin x}{1-r\cos x}$ under suitable restrictions.

Comment: Thanke u very much for your help!